# Is Ubuntu One getting a new logo to coincide with the new(ish) branding?

Tags: ubuntu-one, branding

Seems by now Ubuntu One should update their logo to match the branding introduced in April of 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we will be getting a new logo.

Comment: By Natty's release?

Comment: That's a fair question, but I can't answer it yet :)